# How to modifying the data structure of array list as per key value using PHP

Tags: php

I need to modify the data structure of json array list as per some key value using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
$output=array(
    array(
        "first_name"=>"robin",
        "last_name"=>"sahoo",
        "reg_no"=>12,
        "paper_code"=>"BA001"
    ),array(
        "first_name"=>"robin",
        "last_name"=>"sahoo",
        "reg_no"=>12,
        "paper_code"=>"BA002"
    ),array(
        "first_name"=>"Rama",
        "last_name"=>"Nayidu",
        "reg_no"=>13,
        "paper_code"=>"BA001"
    )
);
//echo json_encode($output);
$result=array();
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    if (count($result)==0) {
        $result[]=array(
            "name"=>$value["first_name"].' '.$value['last_name'],
            "reg_no"=>$value['reg_no'],
            "paper1"=>$value['paper_code'],
            "paper2"=>"",
            "paper3"=>"",
            "paper4"=>""
        );
    }
}
```

The output of the input array is given below.

```
// Output:
[
    {
        "first_name":"robin",
        "last_name":"sahoo",
        "reg_no":12,
        "paper_code":"BA001"
    },
    {
        "first_name":"robin",
        "last_name":"sahoo",
        "reg_no":12,
        "paper_code":"BA002"
    },
    {
        "first_name":"Rama",
        "last_name":"Nayidu",
        "reg_no":13,
        "paper_code":"BA001"
    }
];
```

The above is my array list. Here I need to modify the all row value by `reg_no` means if there are multiple rows including same `reg_no` then those will merge with joining the both name and my expected output should like below.

**expected output:**

```
[
    {
        'name':"robin sahoo",
        "reg_no":12,
        "paper1":"BA001",
        "paper2":"BA002",
        "paper3":"",
        "paper4":""
    },
    {
        'name':"Rama Nayidu",
        "reg_no":13,
        "paper1":"BA001",
        "paper2":"",
        "paper3":"",
        "paper4":""
    }
]
```

Here `paper1,paper2,paper3,paper4` will be selected serially means suppose same `reg_no=12` has first row `paper_code= BA001` then it will be `paper1=BA001` and second row paper_code=BA002 then it will be `paper2=BA002` and so on. Here I am using PHP to map this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, Let me know..

```
$output=array(array("first_name"=>"robin","last_name"=>"sahoo","reg_no"=>12,"paper_code"=>"BA001"),array("first_name"=>"robin","last_name"=>"sahoo","reg_no"=>12,"paper_code"=>"BA002"),array("first_name"=>"Rama","last_name"=>"Nayidu","reg_no"=>13,"paper_code"=>"BA001"));
//echo json_encode($output);
$result=array();
$temp=array();
if(!empty($output)){
    foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($temp[$value['reg_no']])){
            if(empty($temp[$value['reg_no']]["paper1"]) || $temp[$value['reg_no']]["paper1"] == ""){
                $temp[$value['reg_no']]["paper1"] = $value['paper_code'];
            }else if(empty($temp[$value['reg_no']]["paper2"]) || $temp[$value['reg_no']]["paper2"] == ""){
                $temp[$value['reg_no']]["paper2"] = $value['paper_code'];
            }else if(empty($temp[$value['reg_no']]["paper3"]) || $temp[$value['reg_no']]["paper3"] == ""){
                $temp[$value['reg_no']]["paper3"] = $value['paper_code'];
            }else if(empty($temp[$value['reg_no']]["paper4"]) || $temp[$value['reg_no']]["paper4"] == ""){
                $temp[$value['reg_no']]["paper4"] = $value['paper_code'];
            }
        }else{
            $temp[$value['reg_no']] = array("name"=>$value["first_name"].' '.$value['last_name'],"reg_no"=>$value['reg_no'],"paper1"=>$value['paper_code'],"paper2"=>"","paper3"=>"","paper4"=>"");
        }
    } 
}              
if(!empty($temp)){
    foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
        $result[] = $value;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code May help you

```
<?php
$output=array(array("first_name"=>"robin","last_name"=>"sahoo","reg_no"=>12,"paper_code"=>"BA001"),array("first_name"=>"robin","last_name"=>"sahoo","reg_no"=>12,"paper_code"=>"BA002"),array("first_name"=>"Rama","last_name"=>"Nayidu","reg_no"=>13,"paper_code"=>"BA001"));
//echo json_encode($output);

$result=array();
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    if (count($result)==0) {
        $output[$key]=array("name"=>$value["first_name"].' '.$value['last_name'],"reg_no"=>$value['reg_no'],"paper1"=>$value['paper_code'],"paper2"=>"","paper3"=>"","paper4"=>"");
    }
}echo "<pre>";print_r($output);
?>
```

Comment: Please check my `expected output` array format. I think your code may not produce those type of format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
$result = []; // Initialize result array
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    $name = $value['first_name'] . ' ' . $value['last_name'];

    // check if same name already has entry, create one if not
    if (!array_key_exists($name, $result)) {
        $result[$name] = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'reg_no' => $value['reg_no'],
            'paper1' => '',
            'paper2' => '',
            'paper3' => '',
            'paper4' => ''
            );
    }

    // count array elements with value, then set paper number and value
    $paper = 'paper' . (count(array_filter($result[$name])) - 1);
    $result[$name][$paper] = $value['paper_code'];
}

$result = array_values($result); // reindex result array
$result = json_encode($result);  // Encode to json format
print_r($result); // print result
```

This assumes that `first_name` and `last_name` is always same for each `reg_no`

Comment: Ok but `paper3,paper4` should have blank value there. Please check my `expected output format`.